# How do I use the uiimagepickercontroller to let the user pick multiple images at once?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, uiimagepickercontroller

How do I use the uiimagepickercontroller to let the user pick multiple images at once?  Also how would I display a checkmark next to the preview images as the user selects them?

This photo I found online illustrates what I would like to do:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't do that with the UIImagePickerController. You could replicate the functionality of the UIImagePickerController though. Check out [this project](https://github.com/elc/ELCImagePickerController).